# replace string in multiple files using sed in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I am trying to replace a string with another string in files that are present in subdirectories of a directory.

Below are the string values

```
old_string = gs://common/jars/sap_njdbc_2.12.jar
new_string = ${path_to_jar_file}
```

I have tried like below

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/gs://common/jars/sap_njdbc_2.12.jar/${path_to_jar_file}/g' {} \;
```

I am getting a error like below

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 3: unterminated `s' command
```

How do I achieve my correct result

Comment: you can't use `s/pattern/replacement/` syntax if the pattern has `/` in it.  Instead do  `sed -i -e `s#pattern#replacement#g` .  `-e` supports arbitrary delimiters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your command to like below. It will work

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's|gs://common/jars/sap_njdbc_2.12.jar|${path_to_jar_file}|g' {} \;
```

As you are using `/` in your pattern it will not work. So replace `/` with some other delimiter like `|`.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issues that I can see off the bat:

- You didn't properly escape the forward slashes in your replacement string.
- Your `${path_to_jar_file}` was contained in single quotes, you have to use `"` double quotes.

Try this:

`find ./ -type f -exec sed -i "s/gs:\/\/common\/jars\/sap_njdbc_2.12.jar/\$path_to_jar_file/g" {} \;`

Granted, this is for if you are wanting to use the literal `${path_to_jar_file}` as your question was a little unclear.  Let me know if that works for you.